# After SVN setup on server, what is next?

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubersvn

There is a php project and 5+ developers will work on it. We will be using Eclipse and related svn plugins in order to handle project development better and benefit from version controlling.

We bought VPS server and setup UberSVN (created a repository). Simultaneously I generated the files via a framework, which we are going to use for the project.

Now what should I do next?
Do I need to link repository and files? If so, how?
Should I get files from SVN or server when setting up the project on Eclipse?

Sorry, I couldn't guess what to google.

Comment: Click on this link and start reading: [http://svnbook.red-bean.com/](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UberSVN will get your repo up and running, and take away all the hassle from setup. You'll need to setup your users if you haven't already, see [here](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/admin.html#T9) for details.

Given that you've tagged this with Eclipse you'll want to read the quickstart guide [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted.php).

That should be enough to give you day to day use knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "import" your files into SVN. If you have a stand-alone SVN client, it should have an Import function. If you are using an Eclipse plug-in SVN client, then right-click the project name, and from the pop-up menu select Team > share.